# Why am I getting "NA" values after running the curvefit function in R?

Tags: r

I am using a dataset where I am plotting gas emissions on the y axis and soil temperature on the x axis. I am trying to use the curvefit function to determine the best fit for the data. I am using this code:

```
x <- df2$tsoil
y <- df2$winter_flux
curvefit(x, y, plot.curves = TRUE)
```

And my output gives me values for the linear fit, but not the power, exponential, or logistic fits. All the values for those three are just NA. And the plot only shows a linear line. What am I missing here?

**Data**

```r
df2 <- structure(list(tsoil = c(-0.5, 5.6, -0.41, 2.92, -2.33, -4.16, -4.45, 
-4.29, -2.52, -0.15), winter_flux = c(0.064, 0.132, 0.486, 0.281, 0.192, 
0.161, 0.143, 0.146, 0.141, 0.082)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 39L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: could you share `dput(head(df2,10))`?

Comment: structure(list(tsoil = c(-0.5, 5.6, -0.41, 2.92, -2.33, -4.16, 
-4.45, -4.29, -2.52, -0.15), winter_flux = c(0.064, 0.132, 0.486, 
0.281, 0.192, 0.161, 0.143, 0.146, 0.141, 0.082)), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 39L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Thanks, from which package is curvefit?

Comment: REAT is the package for curvefit

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that none of the models used in `curvefit` other than the linear regression can be fit properly to your data.

We can probably demonstrate this more easily if we use `ggplot` to plot your data points:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df2, aes(tsoil, winter_flux)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
p
```

[image]

The first things to note is that there are only 10 points, and there is no obvious pattern to them, so we should be surprised to find a good fit from *any* simple curve. If we look at the code inside the function `curvefit`, we see that there are 4 linear models produced: `y ~ x`, `log10(y) ~ log10(x)`, `log10(y) ~ x` and `log((max(y) * 1.001 - y)/y) ~ x`

We can plot these in ggplot because it will simply skip the infinities generated rather than returning all `NA` as `curvefit` does:

```r
p + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, 
                colour = "black") +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = log10(y) ~ log10(x), se = FALSE, 
                colour = "red") +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = log10(y) ~ x,
                se = FALSE, colour = "blue") +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = log((max(y) * 1.001 - y)/y) ~ x,
                se = FALSE, colour = "green")
```

[image]

None of these lines is at all convincing, as we suspected from plotting the points, and there's really nothing in these data points to provide evidence for a relationship between these two variables. That's not to say that there *isn't* a relationship, but if there is one, it will require more than 10 data points to uncover it.

Comment: My dataset has over 1,000 observations, but I think I figured out my problem. Since some of my values are negative, doesn't taking the log of the function cause issues and that's why the data is producing NAs? How would I fix that?

Comment: @Katherine that's right - the specific forms of the regressions in `curvefit` just aren't right for your data because of the log transformations, and to be honest it's a pretty limited function. If you are able to edit your question (just click on the gray "edit" under your question) to include a more representative subset of the data (say, 100 data points, but the more the better), it should be possible to guide you, but there's only so much anyone can tell you with 10 data points. This is the point I make at the end of my answer.